# jQuery JSONP, only works with same site URLs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp, http-post

I need to make a request to an API which returns json formatted data. This API is on a sub-domain of the domain this script will run off (although at the moment it's on a totally different domain for dev, localhost)

For some reason I thought that jsonp was supposed to enable this behavior, what am I missing?

Using jQuery 1.4.2

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://another.example.com/returnsJSON.php',
    data: data,
    dataType:'jsonp',
    type: "POST",
    error: function(r,error) {
        console.log(r);
        console.log(error);
    },
    success:function(r){
    console.log(r);
    }
});
```

Comment: ed209, can you explain how your accepted answer (changing "POST" to "GET") fixed this issue for you?  Just wondering because I didn't think that would accomplish what you needed to accomplish...

Comment: I was also responsible for the jsonp outputted at 'http://another.example.com/returnsJSON.php' and I did include the callback method in the returned php. Changing to GET was only part of the solution, for some reason I wasn't getting the callback method when using POST on the 'returnsJSON.php' script. So actually your initial paragraph answer summed it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a combination of Arnaud's answer (don't use POST) and R. Bemrose's answer (make sure server-side returns JSONP), with the added specification of a callback function.

In other words, here's your modified request code:

```
function dosomething(data) {
    console.log(data);
}

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://another.example.com/returnsJSON.php',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'jsonp'
});
```

Helpful to note that in the generated code you'll see that when the dataType is "jsonp", jQuery outputs a script tag pointing at the url; it's not a typical XHR.  You could also use [jQuery's getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) here.

Then your response will have to be formatted as such:

```
dosomething({
    test: 'foo'
});
```

When the call is complete, your specified callback will fire.

Answer (score 3):

Change your type from "POST" to "GET".
That is, only if you intend to retrieve data.

Answer (score 1):

Did you modify the server-side component to use JSONP?

You can't just tell the client to use JSONP and suddenly expect a JSON script on the server-side to return the correct result.

Specifically, JSONP requires the server to return a JavaScript string that calls a specific function (whose name is passed in with the other arguments) with the return results, which the client then `eval`s.